# Excel VBA: Copy two columns in a different file

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I am relatively new to VBA and have a few questions.

In the end, my code should copy data from different files into a main data sheet.

I do not know the different names of the different files (this is already covered), because there will be new generated data every once in a while. All these files are `xlsx`.

The only thing I am missing is that my code copies the data from different files in the range "a18 - end of column a" and "b18 - end of column b". By end of column I mean that there is no data left.

Unfortunately I do not know how to copy this and also how to store ALL the data from all the different sheets into my main sheet without overwriting the data.

Code:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim strFile As String, strPath As String, strType As String
    Dim wbX As Workbook, wksX As Worksheet, wksN As Worksheet
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strPath = "C:\..."
    strType = "xlsx"
    Set wksN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lngCount = 1
    wksN.Range(wksN.Rows(lngCount), wksN.Rows(wksN.UsedRange.Rows.Count + lngCount)).Delete

   strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*." & strType)
   Do Until strFile = ""
       'Debug.Print (strFile)
       Set wbX = Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\" & strFile)
       Set wksX = wbX.Sheets(1)
       wksN.Cells(lngCount, 1) = wksX.Cells(1, 1)
       lngCount = lngCount + 1
       wbX.Close False
       strFile = Dir
   Loop
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   wksN.SaveAs Filename:="Main"
End Sub
```

At the moment, my code copies all the a1 cells from all the xlsx-files in my folder and pastes the content one below the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code opens each and every file from a target folder and merge it as one,

Code:

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("\\C:\ update the target folder")
 Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
 'Here it will open each and every file in the target folder
 For Each everyObj In filesObj
 Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
' Paste it in the Macro sheet's non empty row
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close 
Next
End Sub
```

Than You

Comment: wow thank you for your quick answer! interesting, but thats not what i meant. i dont want to merge it that way because that way the order gets lost. i just want to copy column a18 till the end and b18 till the end and that for every xlsx file. also the data should not be overwrited. in the main file i want the range a18 - end/ b18 - end from every file in my subfolder.

Comment: Then you can fix the copying range as Range("A18:B" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
above code takes care of avoiding override